# User appears twice in the user list of a chat room

Tags: bug, chat

In a chat room, **one user's avatar was shown 2 times**. Is this a bug, or a problem in my browser?

[image: screenshot]

#### Update

I have chatted with that user and she said:

> @Angelica lol! i usually use the office pc, but today i logged in thru my home pc so it's showing 2 ppl in your browser
>
> you can just re-fresh the page

I refreshed a few times, and then it shown that user only once in that list.

Comment: Yes, I show that too, and strange thing is that when i tried to view her profile it was always giving me "Page Not Found" error.

Comment: Lucifer's report of a Page not Found on the profile makes me suspect that this was actually an account merge issue, i.e. for whatever reason she briefly had two accounts that were quickly fixed. Unless someone sees it again, I'm not too concerned... But don't get me wrong: I am grateful that it is reported.

Comment: Care to turn the update into an answer? After all, it seems that that reply answers your question.